# Drupal 9 linking CiviCRM Contribution pages to Webforms

Tags: civicontribute, drupal-9

I am fairly new to CiviCRM. We are quite a long way down the road upgrading a D7 site to D9 whilst also restoring a CiviCRM database and upgrading from 5.10.2 to 5.47.1.

In the older D7 site we are able to link to a specific contribution page from within Webforms.

[image]

But within D9 we only have the option to answer yes / no to this same option.

[image]

Any guidance on how to link Webforms to contribution pages in D9/CiviCRM would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

The whole approach to 'using Contribution pages' was done away with in recent webform_civicrm and the whole configuration is now available within the webform_civicrm configuration.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the documentation at

- https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/examples/contributionwebform/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/configure-elements/elements-contribution/

have been updated yet.

Comment: Thank you for this. That makes sense. We found the documentation and it looked like it should work in the old way. I guess if we want to set fixed contribution amounts we do that by editing the Contribution Amount form field variables.

Comment: Yep you do all that on the webform component